# How can I roll (and repeat) a dice roll of 4d6 drop lowest in Fantasy Grounds?

Tags: dice, fantasy-grounds

I'm trying to roll up a new character in Fantasy Grounds and ideally want to roll 4d6 and drop the lowest. So far I can do:

```
/die 4d6
```

Questions:

1. How do I 'drop the lowest'?
2. What is the command to repeat the last entry into the chat bar?

Answer (score 10):

### Fantasy Grounds Unity Added "Drop Lowest" Functionality

Fantasy Grounds Unity added this functionality when it was released in 2020. The chat command to roll 4d6 and drop the 1 lowest is `/die 4d6d1`.

For a list of all supported dice roll expressions see the [Fantasy Grounds Unity Wiki](https://fantasygroundsunity.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/FGCP/pages/2109571073/All+Things+Dice#Supported-Dice-Expressions).

As far as I know, there is still no "repeat the last entry" chat command, but you can still create a shortcut in one of the quick slots for any command. You can also use the up and down arrow keys to cycle through previously entered chat commands.

### Original answer from December 2019

### That functionality is not present in core Fantasy Grounds as of release 3.3.9.

There is no `/die` command in core FG that will drop the lowest die roll.

Some rulesets contain limited "drop the lowest" functionality, for example, the 5e ruleset allows for d20 rolls with advantage. The 5e ruleset also has some "drop the lowest" functionality built into the character builder in "Manage Characters" mode only (when you launch FG, click the "Manage Characters" button).

There are some third-party extensions that add more robust "drop the lowest" functionality.

- [DMFirmy's "Drop Lowest" Extension](https://www.fantasygrounds.com/forums/showthread.php?22637-DMFirmy-s-Drop-Lowest-Extension)
- [MoreCore](https://www.fantasygrounds.com/forums/showthread.php?34860-MoreCore-Ruleset)
- [DORCore](https://www.fantasygrounds.com/forums/showthread.php?42221-DORCore-An-Advanced-Beta-Release-Of-A-New-Ruleset)

For example, with MoreCore installed, the command `/rolld 4d6x1` will roll 4d6 and drop the 1 lowest result.

There is no "repeat the last entry" command either. You can, however, create a shortcut in one of the quick slots for any chat console command.

Source: My own experience playing and DMing 5e in Fantasy Grounds.

Comment: We made a modified a version of DMFirmy's to implement savage attacker.  It worked pretty well.